# link_to nested url from not nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make rails app.

I have this model

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I made this routes.rb

```
resources :companies do
  resources :orders, except: [:index] do
  end
end
resources :orders, only: [:index]
```

This is my orders controller

```
def index
  @orders = Order.all
  @company = Order.first.company
end
```

This is my orders/index.html.haml

```
- @orders.each do |order|
  = link_to 'show', company_order_path(@company, order)
```

What I want to do is making a `link_to` helper to `company_order_path` from `orders#index`. If you know or have an idea, please advise me.

If I clicked show in my oreders#index, it links to companies/1/orders/:id.

Comment: You load all `Order`, by only the `Company` of the first order. How do you plan to build links if there are orders in the array that do not belong to the same company? Do you care?

Comment: I show orders belong to a company in companies#show. But I want to show all orders in orders#index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `orders` belong to a `company` you can write:

```
- @orders.each do |order|
  = link_to 'show', company_order_path(order.company, order)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've done it. I very appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you have code something like

```
- @orders.each do |order|
  = link_to 'show', company_order_path(@company, order)
```

Comment: This is my index.html.haml
- @orders.each do |order|
      %tr
        %td= link_to 'show', company_order_path(@company, order)
Sorry I forget write.